# Returning observable using if/else statement is not working with RxSwift flatMap

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

When using if/else to return a or b base on the condition, i got this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<_.Element>' to specified type 'Observable<Int>'`

```swift
let a = Observable.of(1)
let b = Observable.of(2)
var test = true
let c: Observable<Int> = Observable.of(3).flatMap { _ in
    if test {
        return a
    } else {
        return b
    }
}
```

But when i changed to conditional operator, it worked fine:

```swift
let a = Observable.of(1)
let b = Observable.of(2)
var test = true
let c: Observable<Int> = Observable.of(3).flatMap { _ in
    return test ? a : b
}
```

Why does the first one not work? What is the different between to cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift compiler usually has a hard time inferring types, especially with complex frameworks such as RxSwift. You can (and usually should) help the compiler by explicitly stating your intent and declaring the return type for the closure, e.g.:

```
let a = Observable.of(1)
let b = Observable.of(2)
var test = true
let c: Observable<Int> = Observable.of(3).flatMap { _ -> Observable<Int> in
    if test {
        return a
    } else {
        return b
    }
}
```